# Blender freezes when using Texture painting or weight painting

Tags: blender

Blender is freezing when using Texture painting and Weight painting.

System Config:

Processor: i7-9750H
RAM: 32GB
Graphics: GTX 1660Ti Max-Q,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering your system specs, that is a very weird thing to happen. I suggest that you should check the poly count and try to make a little low poly, because it is possible that your madel is having too many polygons for the program to handle. If this is not the case, try reinstalling blender's latest version (which is 2.82 I guess)
To undo the subdivision surface modifier, use the decimate modifier with the option to Un-Subdivide.

Comment: Tried 2.82 and 2.83a. Even 2.79 is having similar issues.

Comment: @KunalDas Did you try lowering the polygon count? That may help.

Comment: i guess after appying subdivision modifier made it happen  but now how can i reduce the polygon count now

Comment: @KunalDas See edited answer. Please mark it as answer if it works for you.